# filter() or subset() all the dataframes stored in a list

Tags: r, list, dataframe, filter, subset

If I want to remove all the rows that contain 0s in a specific column, I can just do:

```
df <- data.frame(a = c(0,1,2,3,0,5), 
                 b = c(1,2,3,5,3,1))

df <- filter(df, a != 0)
```

How can I do the same if I'm working with lists? 
My intuition tells me to use 'lapply' but I cannot seem to make the syntax work:

```
#same dataframe.
df <- data.frame(a = c(0,1,2,3,0,5), 
                 b = c(1,2,3,5,3,1))

df2 <- df 
list.df <- list (df, df2)

lapply(list.df, filter(), a !=0) #don't work. How do I fix this syntax?
```

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have other options using `lapply` as:

```
#Without dplyr
lapply(list.df, function(x)x["a"!=0,])


#With dplyr
library(dplyr)
lapply(list.df, function(x)filter(x,a!=0))

# Result  
# [[1]]
# a b
# 1 1 2
# 2 2 3
# 3 3 5
# 4 5 1
# 
# [[2]]
# a b
# 1 1 2
# 2 2 3
# 3 3 5
# 4 5 1
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Can you please elaborate on the syntax ```function(x) filter(x, !=0)``` How is that you use an undeclared variable in the function(x). Moreover, in what cases do I need to add ```function(x)``` before the actual function I'm using, that is ```filter```

Comment: The condition `a!=0` can not be passed as parameter to `dplyr::filter` if you use it directly in `lapply`. Hence and inline function as `function(x)filter(x,a!=0)` is introduced that usages condition `a!=0`.

Answer (score 2):

One option involving `purrr` could be:

```
map(.x = list.df, ~ .x %>%
     filter(a != 0))

[[1]]
  a b
1 1 2
2 2 3
3 3 5
4 5 1

[[2]]
  a b
1 1 2
2 2 3
3 3 5
4 5 1
```